# Is there a black-hole information equation?

Tags: black-holes, entropy, information, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

According to some sources, black-hole information is proportionate to the surface area, and, the equation trotted out is $$S = \frac{A k}{4 l_p^2}.$$  But according to another source, the entropy and information aren't the same.  I will add that they don't seem to correlate.  Entropy always stays the same or increases, but somehow information is lost when it it enters a black hole. So is there an information equation that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Could you put these sources in your question as links so we can see them?

Comment: Entropy is a measure of uncertainty. In that sense it quantifies how much information we are lacking in order to know everything that there is to know about the system. So a large entropy means that we have actually very little information and zero entropy means that we actually know all that there is to be known. That is the way in which I view the relation between entropy and information. Corrections are welcome if my understanding is wrong though.

Comment: Sources include Susskind lectures on youtube and answers and comments to black-hole questions at this site.  Sorry that I didn't keep track of them.  I figured someone would simply post an information equation if one exists.

Comment: Gold 3, your view makes sense to me, but it looks like black hole theorists are claiming black hole entropy and information are correlated.

Comment: Entropy is a measure of information, but it's specifically information that we *don't know*. That is basically what @Gold already commented.

Comment: information is not conserved, that's a mindbogglingly persistent myth among physicists that keep ignoring that measurements cannot be expressed as unitary transformations

Comment: d_b, that's not what I heard.  The information is known: the mass, angular momentum, and charge.  But this is not necessarily the information that went in, and, it is believed that such information is lost.  If the entropy stores information we don't know, then surely we can get to know it; yet, the entropy would still be the same or increase.  There wouldn't be an information paradox if all we have to do is examine bits we are simply ignorant of.

Comment: lurscher, that's has been my gut feeling.  If the information is correlated to the surface area along with entropy, then like entropy, it should stay the same or increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple notions of information being used in this question. The main issue is that they are not the same. Let me first notice three points:

1. Yes, entropy is related to information (or at least to the lack of it);
2. Yes, in some sense information is lost in black holes;
3. In the previous two points, I used the word "information" with two completely different meanings.

#### Entropy and Information

Entropy can be understood, under the light of [information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory), as the lack of information of a system, as pointed out in the comments. Systems with high entropy are those about which we have low information about, while systems we have complete information have zero entropy. Notice how this relates nicely with the picture of micro and macrostates: we always know the macrostate of a system, but the specific microstate is unknown. The entropy grows with the number of microstates. Hence, the less we know about what is the specific microstate (i.e., the more microstates there are), the larger the entropy.

In this context, we mean information in the sense of information theory.

For an accessible discussion about this theme, I particularly recommend the review article *Entropy? Honest!* by Tommaso Toffoli (DOI: [10.3390/e18070247](https://doi.org/10.3390/e18070247)).

#### Entropy of a Black Hole

The result you quoted, which in [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) reads
$$S = \frac{A}{4},$$
is derived from the [laws of black hole thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#The_laws_of_black_hole_mechanics) in connection with the prediction of [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_temperature). Hawking radiation establishes the temperature of a black hole to be $$T_H = \frac{\kappa}{2\pi},$$
where $\kappa$ is known as the [surface gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gravity) of the black hole. For a [Schwarzschild black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) (an uncharged, non-rotating black hole), $\kappa = \frac{1}{4 M}$. From the analogy between the first law of black hole thermodynamics with the usual first law of thermodynamics one then reads the entropy of a black hole to be the formula you quoted.

#### Information Loss in Black Holes

And then there is information loss in black holes. This is a consequence of Hawking radiation when one trusts the computation (which is done using [Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime)) up to arbitrarily small sizes. Here's the summary: Hawking radiation leads to black hole evaporation, meaning the black holes get smaller and smaller. The smaller the black hole, the more intense the radiation, and hence it gets smaller even faster. If we trust the computation for arbitrarily small black holes (even when [Quantum Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) effects might come into play), we get the black holes to completely evaporate and vanish.

The thing this time is that [black holes are completely characterized by their mass, charge, and angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem). So if we pick, for example, a gargatuan amount of [neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) and make a black hole out of them, and them pick the same mass and angular momentum out of [neutrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron) and make a black hole out of them, then we wouldn't be able to distinguish which black hole is which. Eventually, via Hawking radiation, the black holes could completely evaporate and there would be no way of telling that one of the black holes was made of neutrons while the other one was made of neutrinos. Someone who had only seen the final black holes would have no way of knowing what the black holes were made of in the first place. In this sense, information was lost.

Notice that this time I did not mention information theory nor anything of the sort. The reason is that in this context, the word information is meant in a more colloquial way, just to mean that if you had complete information about the universe at an instant following the black holes' evaporation, you wouldn't have sufficient data to reconstruct what happened in the past. Another way of stating this is saying that time evolution is not [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_(physics)).

For more on this theme, I'm particularly fond of the paper *Information Loss* by W. Unruh and R. Wald (arXiv: [1703.02140 [hep-th]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02140)).

#### Summary

There is no "information equation". Furthermore, the question uses the word "information" in two completely different senses. Unfortunately, terminology in black hole physics can often be difficult to follow.

Comment: Thank you, Nickolas.

Comment: @garmichaels You're welcome! If the answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: One followup question re: "Entropy can be understood, under the light of information theory, as the lack of information of a system, as pointed out in the comments. Systems with high entropy are those about which we have low information about, while systems we have complete information have zero entropy."

If I encounter a system with high entropy and learn more about its bits, does the entropy decrease?  If I'm an omniscient being, would the entropy of the universe fall to zero?  This seems to violate the second law of thermodynamics which says nothing about how much we know or don't know.

Comment: @garmichaels I would say that is actually worth a new question. In short, yes, if you peek at the system the entropy decreases, but there are a bunch of details that have to be taken into account (both the specific definition of entropy, or the entropy increase due to you peeking – notice the similarity of your example with Maxwell's demon). Also, entropy is not a physical property that can be measured, it depends on the particular description you are using and the information you have. Different observers attribute different entropies to the same thing

Comment: The review paper by Toffoli I mentioned discusses these matters extensively and in a pedagogical way. It is a bit long, but addresses all of the issues you raised in this comment

Comment: "Also, entropy is not a physical property that can be measured,"

So you can't just measure the temperature and energy?  s = E/T.

Comment: @garmichaels that expression is not general. If I recall correctly, it already fails, e.g., for blackbody radiation. Please have a look at the paper by Toffoli I mentioned.